Safari on iPhone says I have 10 tabs open when I have none open
I’ve been trying to work out why Safari on my iPhone is saying I have 10 tabs open when I have none.
I clear the history for the last hour and close all tabs in the same window, however a few minutes later the tabs reopen (sometimes it’s 6 tabs sometimes it’s 9 tabs this time it’s 10 tabs) as seen from the clear history screen on iPhone.
Has anyone ever experienced anything similar?
I’ve attached a picture for clarity. Any insight would be much appreciated.
Thanks


I assume you have tried rebooting the phone. If you have then it might be good to say so.

I’ve rebooted the phone, I still have the same issue, not sure whether to take it to the Apple Store. It was getting very warm while charging over night also.

You can try offloading Safari. If that does not work, try deleting it and reinstalling it. But you will lose bookmarks, website data etc.

Are they in a different tab group

No other tab groups I’m pretty sure, does anyone think this could be malware related?
